# Spring bean creation failed. Can parameter type of the setter be parent of the return type of the getter?

Tags: java, spring, apache-commons-dbcp

I am facing this exception while creating bean of datasource from DBCP2. Exception is

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'connectionInitSqls' of bean class [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource]: Bean property 'connectionInitSqls' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

here is my bean configuration

```
<bean id="fileStore_dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" lazy-init="true">
    <!-- Just that property which causes problem -->
    <property name="connectionInitSqls">
        <list>
            <value>#{filestore.jdbc.connectionInitSql}</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>
```

Here is the setter and getter code for connectionInitSqls in BasicDataSource class. version of DBCP2 is 2.1.1

```
private volatile List<String> connectionInitSqls;

public List<String> getConnectionInitSqls() {
    final List<String> result = connectionInitSqls;
    if (result == null) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return result;
}

public void setConnectionInitSqls(final Collection<String> connectionInitSqls) {
    if (connectionInitSqls != null && connectionInitSqls.size() > 0) {
        ArrayList<String> newVal = null;
        for (final String s : connectionInitSqls) {
        if (s != null && s.trim().length() > 0) {
                if (newVal == null) {
                    newVal = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                newVal.add(s);
            }
        }
        this.connectionInitSqls = newVal;
    } else {
        this.connectionInitSqls = null;
    }
}
```

You can see that argument in setter is Collection which is Super type of List. But I dont know why spring could not instantiate the bean. Is this Spring problem or Bug in DBCP2 code. Can we give parent type of property in setter argument? 
How can I resolve this problem? Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring will use reflection to find the setter property. So it will find the setter using setConnectionInitSqls and argument list because of the property type(which it will find from getter method getConnectionInitSqls) and it will not find therefore the exception.

Exception message is self explanatory now. Note that the property may not exist at all. Spring just works with getters and setters. It finds the appropriate setter method using the getter method's( which is easy to find just prefix with get and no arg method) return value type.

> Bean property 'connectionInitSqls' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. **Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter**?`

you can try using **MethodInvokingFactoryBean**.

```
<bean id="fileStore_dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" lazy-init="true">
</bean>

<bean id="customInjector"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="fileStore_dataSource" />
    <property name="targetMethod">
        <value>setConnectionInitSqls</value>
    </property>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>#{filestore.jdbc.connectionInitSql}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Alternative way:**
I would **prefer this** as it is **SAFER**. Reason being all properties are set during the instantiation phase itself. And then wiring between the beans happen. In the previous case it may be error prone because setting connectionInitSqls happens at a different time and chances are that connections might have already been created(without looking into the internals of the implementation of BasicDataSource).

```
public class CustomBasicDataSource extends BasicDataSource{
    public void setConnectionInitSqls(List<String> connectionInitSqls) {
        super.setConnectionInitSqls(connectionInitSqls);
    }
}
```

replace with this class in xml

```
<bean id="fileStore_dataSource"
    class="org.company.somepackage.CustomBasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" lazy-init="true">
  ...<!-- rest remain same-->
</bean>
```

Comment: Your Explanation is bit confusing! The parameter type in setConnectionInitSqls is Collection which is Parrent Interface of List. Is not Spring allow this? is parameter type Must be equal to Type of Property?

Comment: But Collection could be set or any other type. Say if spring accepted Collection and we are passing a set type then it means that a set could be assigned to a list type which is absurd. Remember this is a setter method not just any other method. see spring uses reflection. Now it knows the name of the method and type of the property which is list. So it will try to find the method through reflection with these parameters. Why should spring try for its base  types.

Comment: This code is from Apache Commons DBCP2 Library version 2.1, IMO Basic Reason behind this setter is to give freedom of any collection type, either It is list, or set. Why not Apache developers think of this problem because mostly in legecy applications we still use xml base configuration for spring to define dataSoure. Any thoughts? Should I mark this as bug in DBCP2 Jira ?

Comment: There is nothing functionally wrong with that code in my opinion. But spring uses this convention. Convention here is causing issue because of reflection. Had it been programatically done there would be no issues.You are facing this problem because I did not see anyone use this property in general. I think you can raise this issue. If you ask me I would say there should be another overloaded setter which takes list to solve this issue. May be you can contribute if it can be accepted.

Comment: I will test Your Answer tomorrow, Your suggestion is good and only If Apache Developers allow me to contribute, I love to do. However I have marked it as improvement on DBCP2 JIRA  Issues according to your suggestions that a new setter will be helpful. Thanks and Will inform you tomorrow about the solution worked or not.

Comment: another way of doing would be you can create a new class which extends BasicDataSource and you create this setter and implementation will be just delegating to collection argument setter. Now you can use this class in your xml file. This is a decent approach as well.

Comment: Yes today I applied this approach but my team lead was not happy with this approach and asking a better solution that not involved in extending BasicDataSource class. Then I post this Question here.

Comment: i think you should be confident and then explain him. In my experience this is good and safe approach. I will tell you the reason why I feel this is better. When using spring and wiring beans, it is always safer if all properties are set during the instantiation phase if not there can be discrepancies like connections are already created and then you set this property in BasicDataSource here. Whereas if you do it by extending you are always bound to be safe and there is no harm in creating one class and exposing a setter. We are not implementing any business logic here. I prefer extend method.

Comment: Here is the link to Jira Issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DBCP-473?jql=project%20%3D%20DBCP%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Open

Answer (score 1):

Try `${` instead of `#{`

```
<property name="connectionInitSqls">
        <list>
            <value>${filestore.jdbc.connectionInitSql}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

Comment: No This is not the problem. We Configured this #{ INSTEAD OF default ${

Comment: +Jan Kaufmann , It Could be improvement but Its not a bug or give any error. As ArrayList implements List interface so we can assign ArrayList reference to List, Its just choice you assign it at the time of creation or after that. but your answer is out of context. My Question was why Spring do give exception if Setter parameter type is Parent type of Property?

Comment: It's not that but the injection should performed by the spring container itself, you use `new` than the object it's not maintaned by the container anymore, this is the perspective as to why I saw the assignment looks bit unusual.

Comment: The Object is datasource and connectionInitSqls is its property. we can use new in setter. it will not cause any harm to original object and spring still maintaining the datasource object.

Comment: It's Injecting datasource's property, not the datasource. datasource is just a reference for the injected property.